# Ramda Converge causing error with arity of function

Tags: ramda.js

I thought I had a reasonable handle on how `converge` works, but I've been staring at this problem and its criptic (to me), error message for a bit and nothing seems to be jumping out at me.

#### Minimal Example

```js
const first = pipe(   
  inc,
  num => compose(multiply(num), multiply(num))
)(9)(1);
console.log("First: ", first);

const second = pipe(
  inc,
  converge(compose, [multiply, multiply])
)(9)(1);
console.log("Second: ", second);
```

#### Output:

```js
First: 100
Error: First argument to _arity must be a non-negative integer no greater than ten
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of `converge` is probably pretty close.  This is certainly an understandable thing to try.

The issue here is that when `converge` runs, it creates a new function that will call each of the transformation functions and then pass those results into the main function.  The arity of this return function is the maximum arity of those transformation functions.

Thus `converge (compose, [multiply, multiply])` is roughly equivalent to `curry ((a, b) => compose (multiply (a, b), multiply (a, b))`, since the arity of `multiply` is `2`.  But that means that `compose` won't be called until we have already received both multiplicands.

You can alter this by changing the multiplication function you provide.  This works:

```js
pipe (
  inc,
  converge (compose, [mult, mult])
) (9) (1)
```

with this:

```js
const mult = (a) => (b) => a * b
```

or this:

```js
const mult = unary (multiply)
```

or this:

```js
const mult = uncurryN (1, multiply)
```

I'm afraid that as useful as it often is, Ramda's magical currying can lead to occasional problems like this.  If we ever get version 1.0 out the door, I will try to convince the rest of the Ramda team switch to simple currying for the next version.  Or maybe that's for a different library altogether.

Ramda also desperately needs to work on its error messaging.

Some day.

Comment: Yeah, `unary` works like a charm. I can see that 'the arity of the new function is the same as the arity of the longest branching function' in the docs, but I didn't think through all the repercussions of this. I suppose that with simple currying, `converging` functions with higher arity becomes the challenge instead,